# Allow traffic on the basis of the host DNS instead of the IP that is coming from the internet gateway to the VPC in AWS Network Firewall

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-networking

I am new to AWS that's why, I am asking this question. Is it possible in AWS network firewall to only allow the incoming traffic from outside that comes from a particular DNS. According to my knowledge, it's easily possible with IP address but the problem is that the IP address of the source does not remain same and is dynamic. I have also read in various posts that in security groups we also can not mention DNS and we can only mention IP addresses. I have also read that in AWS network firewall, it's also possible to block traffic for a particular domain that's generated from EC2 instance using firewall but is it possible the other way around? Is it possible to only allow the traffic of the particular DNS that's coming from the Internet gateway to the VPC using AWS network firewall. Can anyone guide me in this regard?

Comment: [Docs](https://aws.amazon.com/network-firewall/features/) write "AWS Network Firewall can filter fully qualified domain names (FQDN)". So please try and let us know what did you discover.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. you are right but actually, according to my understanding, AWS Network Firewall can only filter domain-based outbound traffic. It can prevent the VPCs from accessing domains but in my scenario, I am talking about inbound traffic that comes from internet gateway to the VPC. I want to add some rules in the Firewall so that only a host with a specific DNS (not IP because the IP is dynamic) can access my EC2 instance deployed in the AWS private subnet.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like something you can solve with any security measures available natively from AWS or any reverse-proxy solutions I know.

You are most likely going down a rabbit hole of solving a problem at the wrong abstraction layer.

Can you talk about the higher-order problem you are trying to solve? e.g., what types of clients are you expecting to hit the applications? Where will you collect their DNS names in the first place? Why not use authentication at the application layer (passwords, multi-factor, certificates) to authenticate the sources?